# What is the purpose of ITestServer in Xamarin UI Test framework?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.uitest

I just found this `ITestServer` in the Xamarin UI Test framework which I couldn't find any helpful resource that explains its purpose and usage.

The [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.UITest.ITestServer/) does not say much:

> Provides access to the test server running on the device for advanced scenarios.

So, I am curious to know what this type does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TestServer is the interface between your tests and the app you want to run your tests against. A very good and detailed explanation can be found at the [Xamarin documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/introduction-to-test-cloud/) in the section "The Anatomy of the Test Cloud Framework".